# CSS for image sizing

Tags: html, css

I have the following requirements for some CSS I need to write. I have an image that needs to fit into an area, and its size needs to stay proportional.

I want it to have a max size of 25px width and 25px height. But if it is bigger than 25px width or 25px height, it needs to be resized to fit into those dimensions keeping its proportions.

Right now, I have the following:

```
.imageResizeAccountInfo
{
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 25px;
    overflow: hidden; 
}
```

Is this the correct way to achieve what I am looking to do?

Comment: Using an absolute value vor max-width and height set to auto seems just fine for me. Btw: Check out the _object-fit_ property, which does with images what we already can with backgrounds. There is also a polyfill out there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in css:

```
background-image: url("path/image.jpg")
background-size: contain;
```

Comment: But say I dont want it to take up all the space of the container?

Comment: You can use background-size: 25px auto; if you want your bg to be 25px in a 50px box, the height will be automatically adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest using:

```
background-image: url('yourimage.jpg');
```

&

```
background-size: contain;
```

Which will contain the photo to it's parent's height & width.

Comment: But what if the container is say 50px by 50px. I only want the image to be 25px by 25 px. Would this still work?

Comment: You'll want to make the background-image div 25px x 25px.

Answer (score 0):

This will always give you an image that is 25px wide with a height that is proportional to any resizing that was done.  If you want to programmatically decide if the height or width needs to be resized, you could do that with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this guide](http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html) for maintaining aspect ratios. I use it all the time for pictures and videos (makes youtube videos super easy to resize).

**Note**: This would only work if you know the aspect ratio of the image beforehand, or you add some logic to determine it. If you want something to handle any image that comes in without knowing the dimensions, this won't work.

With similar HTML

```
<div class='imageResizeAccountInfo'>
  <div class='content'>Aspect ratio of 1:1</div> 
</div>
```

Add this CSS

```
.imageResizeAccountInfo{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.imageResizeAccountInfo:before{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;    /* initial ratio of 1:1*/
}
.content{
  position:  absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

And some additional CSS for customization

```
/* Other ratios */
.ratio2_1:before{
  padding-top: 50%;
}
.ratio1_2:before{
  padding-top: 200%;
}
.ratio4_3:before{
  padding-top: 75%;
}
.ratio16_9:before{
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you only need to resize an image at most at 25x25px and keep aspect ratio you only need to set

```
img {
  max-width: 25px;
  max-height: 25px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3rfXa/

there are three cases, a squared image will be resized to 25x25, a portrait image will be resized to somethingx25 and a landscape image will be resized to 25xsomething (with something less than or equal to 25)

maybe i don't really understand the question, cause all the other answers seems to be too complicated for a resize

note that max-width and max-height are not supported on older ie versions